# Use sed to add line of text to firefox prefs file in OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, sed

I need to prevent 750 Macs from updating Firefox, but retain individuals preferences. 
Therefore I must insert a line into a file.

Using a shell script with sed, I am struggling with identifying the line to follow, as it has special characters:

```
sed '/user_pref("accessibility.typeaheadfind.flashbar", 0); /a\
user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);\'$'\n' /Users/username/pathToFile/prefs.js
```

Obviously for now this is printing to screen, but will write out to a file later on.  Any help appreciated.

The source file looks like:

```
# Mozilla User Preferences

/* Do not edit this file.
*
* If you make changes to this file while the application is running,
* the changes will be overwritten when the application exits.
*
* To make a manual change to preferences, you can visit the URL about:config
* For more information, see http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#prefs
*/

user_pref("accessibility.typeaheadfind.flashBar", 0);
user_pref("app.update.lastUpdateTime.addon-background-update-timer", 1298297884);
user_pref("app.update.lastUpdateTime.background-update-timer", 1298282703);
```

I need to insert the line of code pre-mentioned within the sed command as a new line after the first instance of the "user_pref", so the dollar and \n achieve this, if I'm right.

It looks like the code is right and it should work, but doesn't. I'm using the bash shell on OS 10.6.8.

Comment: What is your intent with `...;\'$'\n'`, to put a '$' at the end of a line? And is the `\n` meant to add a newLine into your text? Good luck.

Comment: Otherwise, this looks fine; what are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fixed this myself. Stupid typo:

```
sed '/user_pref("accessibility.typeaheadfind.flashbar", 0);/ a\
```

Compare the above with the original posting and you will notice at the end that the forward slash needed to come right after the semi-colon.

For those interested, I actually settled upon:

```
useris=$(who | grep -v support | awk '{print $1}' | awk "NR==1{print;exit}")
firefoxPath=$(grep "Path=" /Users/"$useris"/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/profiles.ini | awk -F '=' '{print $2}')

sed '/^user_pref("app.update.lastUpdateTime/ i\
user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);\'$'\n' /Users/"$useris"/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/"$firefoxPath"/prefs.js > /Users/"$useris"/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/"$firefoxPath"/prefs.txt
```

You then follow up with replacing the "prefs.js" file with the new one you generated and you have now managed to prevent the Firefox browser from prompting users with an update.